# Why can I use module low(.A(a),.B(b)); in module declaration？

Tags: verilog

I feel confused when I see this in the IEEE Verilog 2001 Standard.
Why can I use `module low(.A(a),.B(b));` in a module declaration？

[image: the picture link is below]

```
module_declaration ::= (From Annex A - A.1.3)
{ attribute_instance } module_keyword module_identifier [ module_parameter_port_list ]
[ list_of_ports ] ; { module_item }
endmodule

list_of_ports ::= ( port { , port } )

port ::= [ port_expression ] | . port_identifier ( [ port_expression ] )
```

Isn't this named port connection supposed to be used for module instantiation, and why is it used for module declarations？
There is some code like this **module complex_ports ({c,d}, .e(f));**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is to be able to separate internal names of the module ports from external names. It is explained in the following example:

```
module mod(.a(ina), .b(outb));
  input wire ina;  // << internal name
  output reg outb;
  
  always @*
    outb = ina;
endmodule

module top();
  reg topa;
  wire topb;
  mod mod(.a(topa), .b(topb)); // << use externa names
endmodule
```

In the above example the feature is not very interesting. It probably can be used to standardize external port names. However, there is one interesting implication, an ability to connect internal 'net' variable to multiple ports:

```
module mod(.a1(ina[0]), .a2(ina[1]), .b(outb));
  input  wire [1:0] ina;  // << internal vector net connected to a1 and a2
  output reg [1:0] outb;
  
  always @*
    outb = ina;
endmodule

module top();
  reg topa1, topa2;
  wire [1:0] topb;
  mod mod(.a1(topa1), .a2(topa2), .b(topb)); // << use externa names
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.port(port)` syntax in a module **declaration** is legal, but it is rarely used.  It is optional; you don't need to use that style if you don't see a need for it.

The `.port(port)` syntax is more commonly used in a module **instantiation**.

Use the syntax that you understand better and which you are more comfortable with.  There is a lot of optional syntax in a large standard such as this.

[See also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4918951/197758).

Comment: Yes! I try ,I can use both port in .port(port)  when named port connection, thanks!